# Is "wheat skin color" a thing in any dialect of English or just a bad translation from Chinese?

Tags: word-usage, dialects

While shopping for action figures, I came across various sellers offering "wheat skin" colored figures, for example [here](https://ekiahobbies.com/zy-toys-1-6-new-design-wide-shouldered-body-in-wheat-skin-color-zy-nb002/) and probably more notably [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/1-6-Super-Male-Body-Wheat-Skin-Pose-able-12-inch-Figure-Doll/268513763).

That color seems to be what I'd have called 'tan' or 'suntanned', and it certainly doesn't match the yellowish color of wheat. So, where does that name come from?

Of course, those figures are probably 99% produced in China, and "wheat" might just be an inappropriate automatic translation from whatever the Chinese word is. And perhaps it started as a bad translation but has caught on by now. Or maybe there are English-speaking countries that use "Wheat skin" this way, for whatever reason.

So, which is it?

Comment: Here are a few published written instances of [*her **wheaten** skin*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22her+wheaten+skin%22), which seems natural enough to *this* native Anglophone (they're *very* few, though). But the only unambiguously relevant instance in Google Books of [*her **wheat** skin*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Godly_Matrilocal_Husband/KvjoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22her+wheat+skin%22&pg=PT622&printsec=frontcover) *(...and beautiful legs)* is from an obviously Chinese writer penning "amateur erotica" in English.

Comment: ....So possibly "wheat skin" is stereotypically attractive to Chinese men - like ["lily white skin"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22her+lily+white+skin%22) is/was attractive to European men.

Comment: I suspect it is a direct translation from Chinese, perhaps 小麦肤色 where  小麦 (xiǎomài) means wheat and 肤色 (fūsè) means skin colour/complexion/ethnicity.  It [seems to be a description of fashionable light skin tone for Chinese women](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%B0%8F%E9%BA%A6%E8%82%A4%E8%89%B2&tbm=isch)

Comment: The Japanese also refer to their complexion as wheat- colored. Pretty close to the mark, actually.

Comment: Reminds me of the term *flaxen-haired* which used to be used to attribute hair color resembling flax (*Linum usitatissimum*), so a shade of blonde. Rather the way one might speak of a “leaden sky” to mean a sky the color of lead.

Comment: Pssst... answers go in the big box down there ⬇️

Comment: I suspect people are not answering because it's not clear if this is on-topic (being about something that's not a usual English phrase), and it might belong better in Chinese SE or elsewhere.

Comment: ... Also, unsupported suggestions are rarely considered substantive enough to submit as answers, though they just may contain a kernel of truth and so be useful 'comments' (they may even be spot on). Or they can be not strictly relevant, but fascinating or hilarious. // My guess is that 'wheat skin' seems odd to those in the west, but contrasts markedly to typical Chinese skin colour, so they are happy to use hyperbole. Compare 'redhead' (the occasional lady with truly red hair still startles me).

Comment: It's definitely chinglish.

Comment: @StuartF, the core of the question is whether *wheat* is used that way 'in any dialect of English', and that is definitely on topic.

Comment: @shoover You can't downvote a comment. Risk aversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of course, those figures are probably 99% produced in China, and "wheat" might just be an inappropriate automatic translation from whatever the Chinese word is.

This comment seems to be the answer:

> I suspect it is a direct translation from Chinese, perhaps 小麦肤色 where 小麦 (xiǎomài) means wheat and 肤色 (fūsè) means skin colour/complexion/ethnicity. It [seems to be a description of fashionable light skin tone for Chinese women](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%B0%8F%E9%BA%A6%E8%82%A4%E8%89%B2&tbm=isch) –
> [Henry](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4333/henry)

It can be seen that both linked figures are the same. It may well be that, in the case of Walmart, the seller has been asked to provide the description or someone has copied the description from the box.

Comment: Accepting this as after one week nobody said that this is a common expression where they are from, and I guess in this case the absence of information is a point of information in itself.